# No Bundle URL Present on my iPhone - React Native

Tags: react-native

when i run my app on iphone i get this message: No Bundle Url[image]
but when run on the simulator, everything works fine.
also when running in debug version , the application does not start on my iphone, but it also works fine on the simulator[image]

I tried to install a clean initialized react-native application on my phone and everything works, but when I try to install my created application, it just throws out.

Answer (score 0):

this helped me. you just need to add this to *.pbxproj shellScript = "export NODE_BINARY=node\n../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh\n";

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26331#issuecomment-528283889